# Low performance of the new Graphical Views in Dynamic Workload Scheduler

Tags: dynamic, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

have you got any tips to optimize the performance of the new Graphical Views when managing hundreds of objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you work with job streams with more than 500 objects (jobs, job streams and dependencies), to optimize the application performance of the new Graphical Views it is recommended that you follow some tips:

**Choose Google Chrome**
Chrome has better performance compared to other browsers. In some cases, it is 4 times faster than other browsers to open Graphical Views containing complex objects. Also, using Mozilla Firefox is preferable to Microsoft Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge.

**Customize and save the job stream layout**
When viewing job streams in the Job Stream View, first customize and save the job stream layout in the Workload Designer modelling graphical view and then open it in the Job Stream View where the same layout is reused to achieve better performance.

**Use Graphical Views on a powerful client in terms of CPU and RAM**
Adequately set the hardware configuration of the client machine from which the Dynamic Workload Console is accessed.